# Date Difference between the latest date and second latest date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a table where I want to get the list of users who latest transaction created_date subtracted by second latest created_date should be equal to or more than 180 days.

Here's how my table looks like:

[image]

Sample Data:

[image]

Basically, I want to get list of only those user_id whose difference between the latest created_at date and second latest created_date is greater than or equal to 180 days. So in the above example, the query should only give me user_id '1' in the output.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? MySQL 8.0 has [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), which may make the query a lot easier. You should check that link and see if you can write the query yourself.

Comment: Hi Andreas! I am using MySQL version 5.7